# validate_presence_of *before* before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Let's say I have a before_validation that checks to make sure the first letter of a name is "y":

```
before_validation :check_name_first_letter_is_y
```

But I want to make sure that the first name is also present:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

But this will run the before_validation BEFORE validating if there's a first name present, right? How would I check if a name is present before running my before_validate?

I could try:

```
after_validation :check_name_first_letter_is_y
```

But will that stop the save method if I return false? Or is it too late because it's already been validated?

Comment: Standard question: Why do you need to do this? What `check_name_first_letter_is_y` is to do if it the first letter is not `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to do this in one call as follows (if I didn't misread your question!):

```
validates :name, presence: ->(rec) { rec.name.initial == 'Y' }
```

**Update:**

Introduce a new `ActiveModel::EachValidator` that checks the first character in the name to be `y` and use the presence validator as you normally would, but ensure presence validator comes before the `name` validator so that presence check is done before checking first letter.

```
# app/validators/NameValidator.rb

class NameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.initial != 'y'
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "First letter in name must be `y`")
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your model, use the following two validations:

```
validates :name, presence: true
valdiates :name, name: true
```

Please refer: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html.

Also would suggest you to come up with a "Railsy" name for `NameValidator` class!

Comment: Can you pass a lambda as validator options?

Comment: @BroiSatse, Yes.  See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html

Comment: Hmmm.. My actual scenario is a bit more complicated than this but I thought I would simplify the question

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to switch validates :name, presence: true to a custom validation e.g. before_validation :name_present?

Comment: @JacksonCunningham, you can have multiple validations on the same attribute.  Remember the order matters.  So check for presence first then check for first letter instead of before_validation.  That should be simpler don't you think?

Comment: but I'm wondering if before_validation :check_first_letter will run before by validates_presence_of :name

Comment: i.e. how do I properly check the name is there before checking the first letter?

Comment: Let me add an update to introduce a new validator that checks the first letter of the name.

Comment: @vee - I am gonna dig on this, as I was nto able to find anything to support that claim in the docs you gave. Passing a lambda directly as a validator options does not seem to do anything. I had a look in the source code of validate and it seems it is equivalent to `validates :name, presence: {with: <lambda>}`, however presence validator ignores `with` key.

Comment: @BroiSatse, please give it a try.  I suppose you also overlooked my answer.  I like your solution as well.

Comment: @vee - I did give it a try. It does work as it does not raise an axception. It does not work as it is no different than `presence: true`. Another thing - the order of validation will not matter, if `name` is nil the second validation will run anyway and will raise `NoMethod` exception.

Comment: @BroiSatse, c'on I thought we were talking about functionality and not about my suggestion does not raise exception.  Also, sounds good on the order.  I would suggest you to try switching the order.  By the way which version of Rails are you on?

Comment: @vee - I thought the whole point of the question was how to avoid this exception. This is pretty much why I asked a question in a comment below the question. Anyway: still think that this lambda won't do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a second format validation:

```
validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: /^y/, allow_blank: true }
```